# Question from the inequality

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I want to prove Caccioppoli inequality:

$\int_U \eta^2 |Du|^2dx\leq C \int_U |D\eta|^2u^2dx$.

I proved this result by using the definition of weak solutions by taking $v=\eta^2 u$,

I proved my result upto here

$\int_U \eta^2 |Du|^2dx\leq \frac{2M}{\theta}\int_U \eta |u| |Du||D\eta|dx$.

I tried to use Holder inequality further to reach desire inequality.

Can anyone suggest me the last step.

Answer (score 1):

Use

$$2 \eta |u| |Du||D\eta| =2(\eta |Du|)(|u||D\eta)\le\epsilon \eta ^2 |Du|^2 +|u|^2|D\eta|^2/\epsilon.$$

Now choose $\epsilon$ so that
$$ \frac{M\epsilon}{\theta} =\frac 12.$$

Then
$$\int _U \eta^2 |Du|^2 \le \frac {M}{\theta \epsilon} \int _U u^2 |D\eta |^2 +\frac 12 \int _U \eta^2|Du|^2$$
and your inequality is obtained by moving the second term on the right to the left.